# Bash key binding or Putty shortcut for moving to next word with control key in Window?

Tags: windows, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, putty

Is there a bash keyboard binding or putty shortcut to move to next word in the terminal?
I found this shortcut to be very useful in Mac, but in Window when using putty, it doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Bash in my terminal, and META-left or META-right work.  META is either holding alt or pressing and releasing Esc before pressing the next key.

Comment: When I press alt+ right or alt+left, I get "[D". What can I do?